# Na adjectivs or i adjectives

Tags: learning

I know (i) adjectives end ai-ii-ui-oi
I adjectives are close cousins to verbs and na adjectives are nouns and my question  きらい is na adjective or i adjective 
I think i adjective because end ai please answer my question

Answer (score 3):

Judging by its form, きらい could be an i-adjective, but it's actually a na-adjective. This is in analogy to すき, so you can view them as a pair.

But more importantly, things like these can be figured out by a quick look at a dictionary. I would personally suggest jisho.org. There, you can type in the Japanese word you want to look up (it accepts Romaji, Hiragana/Katakana and Kanji) and see if it's an i-adjective, na-adjective, verb, etc.